# Можно ли выделить логическим ударением обособленный сравнительный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, орфоэпия, сравнительный-оборот

Долгое общение с оборотами и интонацией вынуждает меня сделать такой вывод: нет, нельзя.

**1. Обособленный сравнительный оборот**

Обособляя оборот, мы исключаем его из основного сообщения. Это уже не член предложения, который является обстоятельством образа действия или степени – теперь это попутное сравнение, **художественный прием**, который характеризует предмет, действие или признак **через сопоставление** его с другим предметом, действием или признаком.

Мы можем расположить обособленный сравнительный оборот **в любой части предложения**,  но логического ударения он не получит. При этом интонационно оборот будет выделен, но  характер выделения зависит от конструкции.

***Мир, как конструктор, для всех слабаков сложен.***

Возможно, автор имел в виду следующее:  Мир сложен для слабаков, как сложен для них конструктор. Но без контекста это трудно понять, да и вообще мысль неясная:  кого мы здесь называем слабаками, о каком конструкторе идет речь?

Если это философия, то понятная запись выглядела бы так; Мир, представленный как конструктор, для всех слабаков сложен (т есть управлять таким конструированием могут только сильные личности).
Поэтому анализировать и выбирать  форму всегда надо с учетом содержания.

**2. Необособленный сравнительный оборот**

Необособленный оборот в роли обстоятельства также может занимать **любую позицию** в предложении.

***Как грАд посыпалась картечь.*** Посыпалась непрерывным потоком.  Это  логически выделенное обстоятельство в основном сообщении.  Но мы без труда превратим оборот в обособленное попутное сравнение, если распространим предложение. *Со всех сторон, **как град**, посыпалась картечь.*  Теперь оборот не входит в основное содержание и обозначает сопоставление ситуаций:  Картечь посыпалась так, как сыплется град. Логическим ударением оборот выделить нельзя.

**И вопрос:** В чем вы согласны и в чем не согласным с тем, что сказано?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133850/discussion-on-question-by-sharon------).

Comment: @Nektoid Прямое значение "послушный" тоже есть в краткой форме. При таком порядке у неверного смысла минимальные шансы. Смотрите: *Духовным мудрецам этот мир послушен, как дитя.* Так уже можно. *потому что "нам" в контексте песни значит "всем"* — да без проблем: *Этот мир, как дитя, всем людям на земле послушен.*

Comment: @oleedd да, вот так разносмысленности нет, поскольку 'послушен вообще' и 'послушен всем людям' воспринимается как синонимы.

Comment: @Nektoid Если у вас нет, то это не значит, что и у других нет. Так и запишем: когда фразы воспринимаются как синонимы, так делать можно, потому что, скорее всего, вас поймут. А вообще, так делать нельзя.

Comment: @Nektoid Многочисленные примеры (с разным порядком) показывают, что такая позиция некорректна в связи с грамматикой, а вы пытаетесь обойти это какими-то синонимическими отношениями и прыгать через зависимые слова.

Comment: @oleedd либо извольте наконец предъявить правило грамматики, где заявлялось бы о "некорректности" или давались бы нормы "корректности" расположения обособленного сравнительного оборота в предложении, либо вам сюда: https://bujhm.livejournal.com/161872.html

Comment: @Nektoid Было много примеров, в которых такая структура некорректна даже для вас. Кучу времени потратил на их составление и доказывание. Жаль, что зря, потому что до вас так и не дошло. А свою награду держите у себя, не надо другим передавать. Есть такая вещь, как детерминант. Так вот сравнительный оборот выступает им для всего того, что стоит после. Вы прикрываете это какими-то синонимическими отношениями. Только вот не для каждого сработает.

Comment: @oleedd извольте правило, что обособленный сравнительный оборот может быть детерминантом. Либо правило, либо вперёд за медалькой.

Comment: @Nektoid А вам эту медальку никуда не засунуть? Заплатите мне, чтоб я сидел целый день в книгах и искал.

Comment: @oleedd если вы вступаете в спор и позиционируете своё мнение как объективную истину, будьте готовы предъявлять объективные доказательства. Либо не тратьте чужое время. Правило, которое я от вас уже три дня жду, — это § 2055 в АГ-80. Если бы вы его привели, мы бы на основе его продуктивно обсудили, является ли "как дитя" детерминантом или нет. Вы же соизволили потратить дни на составление пустопорожних примеров, хотя я неоднократно запрашивал пруфы. Я не против логики, но лишь когда она основана на объективном. Отныне прописываю для вас правила пользования мной: сперва пруфы, потом диспут.

Comment: @Nektoid Пытался найти. Но у меня нет перечня книг, в которых можно искать. Увлекаюсь практическим доказательством. Это для меня порой аргумент весомей, чем ссылка. Ведь по вопросам стилистики иногда ссылок не найти, потому что их нет.

Comment: @oleedd "практическое док-во" без теоретической базы — это часто симулякр. Вы можете полагать иначе, но мне безразлично. Правила пользования мной я для вас прописал; имейте уважение к чужому времени и впредь, пожалуйста, соблюдайте их единственный пункт.

Comment: @Nektoid Никогда не защищаю лишь своё мнение, доказываю лишь то, в чём уверен, как в "2+2=4". Если решать всё одними ссылками, бараном будешь.

Comment: @oleedd да-да, я помню, что вы были как в 2+2=4 уверены, что правильная форма дательного падежа — по чём. Жаль, что этот инцидент вас не научил скептичнее относиться к вашим, так сказать, "уверенностям". Как говорили вы сами: "Даже один некорректный пример показывает, что такая структура неправильная". Так вот, даже одна некорректная "уверенность" показывает, насколько "уверенностям" можно доверять.

Comment: @Nektoid У нас только она правильная, ибо другую не поймут. Про дательный падеж речи не было. Не надо менять понятия.

Comment: @oleedd Niemand тоже постоянно ссылался на окружение. Ему тоже было невдомёк, что "у нас говорят" аргументом вообще не является. // Речь шла именно про дательный падеж; но вы потёрли комменты — видать, чтобы не было улики. Хотя ничего стыдного в незнании нет.

Comment: @Nektoid Нет, не про дательный, а про "по чём". Здесь предложный. Не моя вина, что другой вариант не слышал. Да всё я понимаю. Ну живите одними правилами, сочувствую вам.

Comment: @oleedd там был именно дательный, "по кому/чему". А что вы не слышали — вина именно ваша, потому что в школьном курсе падежи проходят. // Про "одни правила" — очередное ваше невнимание, потому что выше я яснее ясного написал: "Я не против логики, но лишь когда она основана на объективном".

Comment: @Nektoid Мы вообще не обсуждали, каким должен быть дательный падеж. Не выдумывайте. Что для вас объективно? Лишь правила?

Comment: @oleedd именно это мы и обсуждали. На некоторых форумах я всегда делаю скриншоты сообщений некоторых собеседников, зная их манеру удалять свои тексты и потом отрицать то, что говорили. Пожалуй, в беседах с вами я тоже возьму за правило так поступать.

Comment: @Nektoid Жесть. Мы обсуждали, какой вопрос задать. Про дательный падеж ничего не утверждал. Что для вас объективно? Лишь правила?

Comment: @oleedd в вашем случае для меня да, объективны лишь правила. Потому что я понял а) уровень вашей квалификации и б) вашу оценку собственного уровня квалификации. Это максимальный ответ, на который вы можете рассчитывать. Простите, не имею ни времени, ни желания длить эту перепалку. Все ваши беспруфные попытки вызвать меня на дискуссию отныне я буду игнорировать.

Comment: @Nektoid Жаль, что вы по одному случаю делаете такой вывод. Ноль в вас объективности.

Comment: @Nektoid Хороший у вас принцип: без правил ты какашка. Аж противно от такого подхода. Вы формалист. Теперь понятно, почему вы любитель (указано в профиле), а не профессионал. Тогда этот сайт надо переименовать из "Русский язык" в "Правила русского языка". Или вы местом ошиблись. Не на всё есть правила. С этим трудно поспорить. Как вы предлагаете найти то, чего нет?

Comment: @oledd не по одному. Я читаю почти все диспуты здесь и, разумеется, вижу ваши заплывы в свободные рассуждения — без руля и без ветрил. Это ваше право, но моё право — просить, чтобы ваше право не касалось диспутов со мной.

Comment: @oleedd я всё написал, перечитайте снова. И про моё отношение к логике, и про то, что я стал применять указанный принцип именно к вам, индивидуально. И про то, почему стал.

Comment: @Nektoid Где заплывы?

Comment: @oleedd не имею привычки коллекционировать чужие промахи, чтобы потом тыкать в них носом.

Comment: @Nektoid Просто вы лишь один нашли. А сколько у вас промахов — в ответах... и сколько раз вы меняли ответ после моих комментариев... Так что давайте не будем. Ваш принцип: вы дурак, но не скажу почему, потому что забыл.

Comment: @oleedd мои промахи я признаю (когда аргументированно указано, в чём промах) и с благодарностью исправляю. В этом и состоит обучение. Что касается ваших промахов: вы правы, пруфов нет, поэтому можете считать, что я сделал вывод на основании одного случая, что объективности во мне ноль и что я формалист. Ярлыки костей не ломят, так что — на здоровье. Только правило использования меня соблюдайте, пожалуйста, а там думайте обо мне что хотите.

Comment: @Nektoid Вы не прокомментировали это: Не на всё есть правила. С этим трудно поспорить. Как вы предлагаете найти то, чего нет?

Comment: @oleedd вы невнимательны. Я заранее, превентивно прокомментировал: "...в вашем случае для меня да, объективны лишь правила. <...> Это максимальный ответ, на который вы можете рассчитывать".

Comment: @Nektoid Это вы невнимательны. Как мне найти то, чего нет? Вы не отвечали.

Comment: @oleedd я даже процитировал.

Comment: @Nektoid Это не объективно. Типа знать ничего не хочу.

Comment: @oleedd я уже написал: можете считать, что объективности во мне ноль: https://is.gd/h2h4Zh Вы опять своей невнимательностью вынуждаете меня повторяться.

Comment: @Nektoid Помню всё, что вы говорили. Не надо спамить. Просто хотел, чтобы вы нормально ответили насчёт того, как доказать таким, как вы, правилами в случае, если таких правил нет. Ну да ладно.

Comment: @Nektoid Знаю это, вы правы. Но для этого [опираться на пред. слои] надо перечитать тонну книг (научных) и быть учёным. Можно гораздо меньше усилий приложить и доказать логически (как теорему) — если у человека хорошо развита логика, он согласится (уверен, что и вы так сможете). Проще доказать на аналогичных примерах. Ну, извините, у меня нет доступа к научным диссертациям. Надеюсь, вы понимаете, что в свободном доступе в интернете лишь доля из всей существующей информации. С тем, что описано 99.9%, категорически не согласен. Тогда бы не было тем для диссертаций, ведь их нельзя повторять.

Comment: @oleedd Информации в интернете нет только по новейшим открытиям, и это может помешать только тем профессионалам, которые уже вот-вот вырвутся за пределы слоёв. Помню, как вы удивились, что в интернете есть в свободном доступе сценарии фильмов: так и диссертации есть. Я писал не что 99,9% описано, а про 99,9% шанс того, что то, что вы "открыли", уже описано. Впрочем, не обращайте внимания: я уже удалил комментарии. Не хочу в ступать в новый виток диалога.

Comment: @Nektoid Диссертации хранятся в научных архивах, и они защищены авторским правом. Лишь единицы проскользнули в интернет.

Comment: @oleedd так никто их пиратить не просит. Многое-многое можно добыть официально. Защищённую диссертацию в тайне не держат — зачем? Она уже достояние научного сообщества. К тому же есть такое понятие, как авторефераты, они вообще выкладываются часто и бесплатно; в них для непрофессионалов достаточно информации.

Comment: @Nektoid Предлагаете мне ехать в Москву, чтобы попасть в архив и найти для вас пруфы? Дорогу хоть оплатите?

Comment: @oleedd под "добыть" я имею в виду электронную форму.

Comment: @Nektoid В смысле? Чтоб кто-то из архива перекинул? Вы что! Это нарушение. На это не пойдут. Они хранятся в бумажном варианте. Может, сейчас уже есть и электронная база. В стилистике АГ-80 не помощник. А самое сложное в ней. Порой там высшая материя. И не сравнить с тем, что описывается в ваших книгах по грамматике! Хоть и всегда стоит элементарный вопрос: "а можно ли так сказать?".

Comment: @oleedd стилистика так же хорошо описана, как грамматика. Я неоднократно ссылался на учебник Голуб по стилистике как на пример.

Comment: @Nektoid Описать можно общие принципы. А частных случаев — бесконечность. Взять даже случай с поэзией.

Comment: @Nektoid Человек нуждается в информации, когда он не способен сам что-то понять, решить либо разобраться в чём-то. Если решать все проблемы лишь поиском информации, то это сделает человека умственным инвалидом. Поэтому лучше буду мыслить, сопоставлять, сравнивать, анализировать, как это делают те же учёные и авторы справочников, чем часами пытаться найти информацию, чтобы слепо поверить кому-то без понимания. С вашим подходом не то что учёным не стать, а даже нормальным филологом.

Comment: @oleedd извольте перечитать снова моё предложение: "Я не против логики, но лишь когда она основана на объективном". Чтобы "мыслить, сопоставлять, сравнивать, анализировать", надо, во-первых, на что-то опираться, кроме своих фантазий, а во-вторых, уметь правильно мыслить, сопоставлять, сравнивать, анализировать. Скажите, сколько учебников по логике вы освоили? Хотя бы один? Имеете представление об основных законах логики? И не извольте впредь перевирать мои мысли: про "непонимание" я никогда не говорил, наоборот: всегда использую термин "усвоить", а не "прочитать" — это разные вещи.

Comment: @oleedd добавлю, что учёными становятся те, кто сперва усердно осваивает материал, накопленный предшественниками, а не изобретает велосипед. Просто потому, что человеческая жизнь слишком коротка, чтобы он самостоятельно смог пройти хотя бы путь в два слоя слоистой горы знаний. Поколение учёных и авторов справочников стоит на плечах прошлых поколений учёных и авторов справочников.

Comment: Ага, теперь вижу. Отвечу чуть позже.

Comment: @Sharon пожалуйста, с упоминанием через @.

Comment: @Nektoid Усвоить? Там ничего не доказывается. Опираться можно на примеры. Если что-то основано на необъективном, извольте на это указать и аргументировать эту необъективность. Если человек мыслит неверно, его утверждения можно опровергнуть. Вы пытались это сделать своим примером с абсурдом. Второй комментарий у вас уже не грубый, с ним согласен. Ни в коем случае не говорю, что можно вообще без этого, говорю, что порой можно и без этого разобраться.

Comment: @oleedd нередко бывает, что человек, мыслящий неверно, просто неспособен понять опровержение вследствие недостаточного уровня понимания. Я, к примеру, и наполовину не понял сегодняшнее дополнение Sharon, поэтому уже полдня сижу и читаю "Синтаксис осложненного предложения" Прияткиной. Но это в целом выше моего уровня, потому что мне приходится на каждой странице по нескольку раз вбивать в поиск незнакомые мне слова из книги, чтобы понять, о чём там вообще говорится. Я полагаю, что в нынешнем случае ваш уровень знаний примерно так же разнится с моим, как мой — с уровнем Sharon.

Comment: @Nektoid Но опровержения в любом случае должны быть. А потом уже можно опровержения опровергать. Смотря какие знания вы имеете в виду. Ага. То есть считаете меня тупее всех. Ну спасибо.

Comment: @oleedd ещё хочу обратить ваше внимание на то, что соотносить себя с учёными и авторами справочников — очевидная переоценка собственного уровня. Вы можете подражать их внешним приёмам, но внутри-то вы hollow, полый, по сравнению с ними (в вопросе конкретной науки, разумеется). А внешнее подражание без внутренней сути — это даже не актёрство... Пародия, в лучшем случае. Не обижайтесь, это не оскорбление, это я из собственного опыта знаю. Хорошо, что я это в себе имел волю увидеть и признать. Как я однажды удачно выразился: "Я знаю то, что ничего не знаю. Многие не знают о себе и этого".

Comment: @oleedd не утрируйте. Ни в коей мере не тупее всех. И не тупее меня в целом. Я рассматриваю лишь конкретную ситуацию. Да и вообще тупость противоположна уму, а знанию противоположно невежество. Можно быть умным, но невежественным. А можно — тупым и многознающим, эрудитом, складом никак не усвоенной информации: просто жёстким диском, а не нейросетью. В вас я вижу ум, но нехватку знаний, бэкграунда. Это нестрашно, если это в себе видеть;  а вот то, что вы пренебрегаете знаниями, ставите свои аналитические возможности выше преемственности знаний — вот это вам мешает и будет мешать.

Comment: @Nektoid Нет, не соотношу, потому что ими не являюсь и нет цели ими стать. Но действую теми же методами. И это не подражание, просто эти методы эффективны. Поверьте, лингвистика и близко не настолько сложна, как математика или физика. Поэтому здесь нет такой колоссальной разницы между учёными и продвинутыми. Розенталь учёным не был, а его справочник лучше (подробнее, понятнее), чем справочник бригады учёных РАН. Тупость тоже заключается в незнании, как и ум в знании. Словари докажут. И ещё не ясно, кто в этой ситуации тупее. У меня ещё есть что сказать.

Comment: @Nektoid Открытие может сделать даже человек, не являющийся учёным. Сейчас даже дети делают открытия. Так что не надо считать всех остальных людей идиотами на фоне учёных.

Comment: @oleedd не стоит возводить случайность в правило. И вы опять перевираете мои слова, придумываете то, чего я не говорил. Надоело. Отстаньте.

Comment: @Nektoid И это от безвыходности. Сперва пытаюсь найти информацию в интернете (знания). Но часто не удается. По продвинутыми вещам часто в интернете информацию не найти. Остаётся пытаться разобраться самому. Так и Sharon поступает. Важно отличать мнение (предположение) от полной уверенности (которая крайне редко подводит).

Comment: @Nektoid Вы иногда образное принимаете за прямое. Образное не значит, что вы говорили именно это. Так что не злитесь.

Comment: @Nektoid Похоже, что вы доказываете не то, что "нам" не входит в сравнение (спор был об этом), а корректность "мир нам послушен, как дитя нам послушно". Оно сопоставимо с "как Бобик нам послушен". Ведь не у каждого есть Бобик. Здесь можно иметь в виду, что послушное дитя слушается всех или что "дитя" означает "дети". Но "нам" все равно входит в сравнение.

Comment: @Nektoid Своими примерами показал, что такую структуру нельзя считать полностью корректной. То, что в некоторых случаях проще воспринять, — другое дело. Но стилистика должна быть такой, чтобы всем было понятно, чтобы не надо было ничего настраивать, иначе с ней проблемы. Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, предыдущий комментарий и этот вариант: *Этот мир, как дитя, им послушен.* Спор закончен, только что подвёл итог, просто хочу расставить все точки над «i».

Comment: @oleedd не хочу.

Comment: @Nektoid Не будьте редиской.

Answer (score 1):

**КОММЕНТАРИЙ** (еще два дополнения от 07.02.2022 г.)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 4. Тождество и сравнение**

1. Отличайте тождество от сравнения, они записываются одинаково! Поэтому требуется расшифровка мысли.

**Тождество** – (1) считая, рассматривая, приравнивая или  (2) являясь (будучи).

**Сравнение** – напоминает, похож  по своей качественной сущности.

**2. Рассмотрим сравнение и тождество на примерах**

**Пример 1.** *Мир, **как дитя**, нам послушен. Мир **как дитЯ** нам послушен.*

Мир похож на дитя своей послушностью. Это сравнение (а также может быть обстоятельством степени при логическом выделении).  Он всегда послушен, но это надо понять и научиться им управлять.

**Пример 2.** *Мир **как конструктор** сложен для слабаков.*

Мир, приравненный к конструктору, рассматриваемый как конструктор, изображенный в виде конструктора, сложен для понимания. Это тождество, здесь нет сравнения. Мир в нашем обычном представлении может быть для понимания любым, простым или сложным.

**Пример 3**. *Мурка,  **как кошка,**  ловит мышей.*

Мурка, являясь (будучи) кошкой, ловит мышей. Это тождество, Мурка – это кошка, то есть она принадлежит к этому роду, поэтому всегда ловит мышей . Мурка  обладает определенным качеством, свойственным этому роду.

**3. Сопоставим тождество и сравнение по качественной сущности**

Мир ВСЕГДА обладает **качеством послушания**, поэтому похож на ребенка. Но мы пока плохо видим это постоянное качество.

Мир ВСЕГДА сложен, ЕСЛИ представить его **в виде конструктора**, отнести к классу конструкторов.  Здесь присутствует значение **условия**.

Мурка ВСЕГДА ловит мышей, так как **является** кошкой, то есть относится к роду кошек.

**4. Есть ли здесь противоречие?**

*Вы хоть чуть-чуть заметили противоречие? Это как: Мурка как кошка ловит мышей?  А как не кошка она не ловит? Она ловит в принципе. Так и с миром. Если он сложен как конструктор, то он сложен в принципе. А мысль в том, что он сложен лишь как конструктор.*

Да, заметили.  *Мир **как конструктор** сложен для слабаков*. Эта фраза неточна (неясно, мир является конструктором или рассматривается как конструктор?).  Правильно: *Мир, **если** его рассматривать как конструктор, сложен для слабаков.*

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 5.  Как добраться до «конечной станции знаний», чтобы дальше двигаться самому**

*Про конечную станцию знаний. Как до неё дойти? Изучить всё, что существует? Ещё ж куча денег нужно, чтоб столько книг купить. Но главное: как получить список всего того, что существует? Нет, учёные изучают то, что им интересно, столько, сколько считают достаточным. Никто не в силах найти всё и получить к нему доступ. Потому что никак не узнать, это всё или же нет.*

Для ученых **интересна** та область, в которой они работают. Туда они направляют максимум усилий, защищают диссертации по этим темам и должны хорошо разбираться в **смежных** областях.

Если вы работаете в области **практического письма**, то для вас важно знание правил в официальных источниках, а также  умение работать со словарями. Но есть и **смежные** области, и в первую очередь это грамматика и отчасти фонетика.

Как здесь найти «конечную станцию»? Можно обозначить нужное вам пространство двумя **координатами.** Первая – это **академические источники**, а вторая – **новые  вузовские учебники** (желательно достаточно известные, но не старше 10 лет).

Почему **учебники?** Там язык попроще  и материал уже устоявшийся, в то время как самые новые разработки должны еще пройти испытание временем. В то же время они вполне на уровне, а большего для правописания и не нужно, и это было бы хорошо освоить.

Вот и крутитесь там. В практике письма часто встречаются **нестандартные задачи** – научитесь их решать, в том числе с помощью примеров из Нацкорпуса. (Придумывать свои без особой надобности очень нежелательно.)

Это область **малоосвоенная**, там вы можете развернуться в соответствии со своими интересами. И обязательно **помните свою «конечную станцию»,** чтобы вернуться туда, если что не так пойдет.

**Использование интонации** при решении практических задач – область совершенно новая, но и здесь надо знать, на что опереться. Основные определения давно сформулированы, и из них желательно построить какую-никакую **модельку для себя.** А дальше строить системное понимание того что есть.

**Наблюдение**, прежде всего. Чтобы сделать вывод, рассмотреть какую-то версию, надо неоднократно увидеть это на практике. А у вас много замечаний, много мыслей на каждую **конкретику** – а общего понимания, единого подхода я не вижу. Вы **не двигаетесь вперед,**  а могли бы, способности у вас хорошие!

Ну всё… Как говорит Jim Korbett,  «устал писать». Так что удачи вам…

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133947/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------).

Answer (score 0):

**КОММЕНТАРИИ**

Уважаемые друзья! Сколько сообщений я получила по этой теме – и не счесть, но так и не поняла, что обсуждали и какой вывод сделали. Совсем вы рассорились  или надежда на примирение еще есть?

Но сейчас не об этом, у меня возник другой вопрос. Может ли приведенное предложение иметь **два разных значения и две формы письма**:

(1) *Мир **как конструктор** для всех слабаков сложен.*

(2) *Мир, **как (и) конструктор**, для всех слабаков сложен.*

Второй вариант я могу дополнить союзом И, но смысл у варианта (2) мне кажется **неопределенным**, в то время как вариант (1) по смыслу полностью **соответствует** теме стихотворения.

Согласны вы со мной или нет? Видите ли вы эти разные значения?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 1** ОТ 06.02.2022 Г.

Уважаемые участники форума,  теперь мне понятно, почему вы уже два дня неизвестно о чем спорите.

**ЗАМЕТКА 1**. Обсуждая конкретное предложение (***мир как конструктор***),  вы сами занимаетесь словесным конструированием, не имеющим смысла. Ваши предложения не имеют права на существование – всё это неправильно построенные модели. Я, к примеру,  на тему синтаксиса могу разговаривать только **при наличии двух условий**: (1) это **правильно построенное** реальное предложение; (2) это предложение коммуникативное, то есть оно описывает **реальную ситуацию** и имеет определенный контекст.

Вот ваш пример: ***Он, как гепард, вокруг дома быстро бегал.***  Мысль неясная, ситуация непонятная, порядок слов нарушен. Чему можно научиться, работая с таким предложением?  (Гепард – быстрейшее из всех наземных млекопитающих: за 3 секунды может развивать скорость до 110 км/ч.)  В качестве сравнения его удобно использовать. Но нельзя БЕГАТЬ, как гепард, вокруг дома. Как гепард, **можно мчаться, или носиться, или нестись.**

Примеры из Нацорпуса:

(1) Она бежит без шума, **как гепард**, и вот уже мы у ее машины.

(2) Правда, быстро? ― Быстр, **как гепард**, ― похвалила она.

(3) Машина оказалась на удивление резвой, с места брала, **как гепард**.

(4) А это уже **ирония** (противоречивое описание преступника, как вариант): Низкий брюнет, два метра ростом, с волосами ярко-пшеничного цвета, **хромал на обе ноги и бежал, как гепард…**

А что можно сделать из вашего предложения? Ну, например, можно сказать так:  *Все это время он  не не мог устоять на месте ни минуты, а быстро, **как гепард,** носился вокруг дома, выискивая новые улики*

**И теперь о конструкторе.** Тема была предварительно задана, поэтому коммуникативность (связь с контекстом) вполне понятна. Вот правильные предложения:

*Мир ***как конструктор*** (= в качестве конструктора) для слабаков сложен.

Мир, **как конструктор собственной реальности**, для слабаков сложен.*

А это уже неверно:

*Мир, *как конструктор*,  для слабаков сложен.* Нет определения для «конструктора»  – и  **семантика расползается на глазах**. О чем здесь речь? *Мир для слабаков сложен* (основное содержание)? Наверное, да, несладко им приходится (конкуренты всегда готовы затолкать локтями), но какую именно ситуацию мы обсуждаем?  Сложен как конструктор? Но какой именно? Теперь вообще полный абсурд…

**ЗАМЕТКА 2.**  Со времени выхода Русской грамматики (АГ-80) прошло 50 лет, **срок немалый**. Некоторые разделы вполне актуальны и сейчас, но **теория синтаксиса** претерпела значительные изменения. Это самая динамичная область в лингвистике, и в частности это касается теории осложненного простого предложения, куда входит и **сравнительный оборот**.

Практика темы освоена неплохо (стилистика, постановка знаков препинания), а вот **теории** этого вопроса до настоящего времени уделялось  недостаточно внимания.  Поэтому так важно читать современную учебную литературу последних лет.

Сравнительный оборот – даже здесь **особый случай.** Он рассматривается в общей теории сочинительных рядов, но отличается большим разнообразием конструктивных особенностей.  В особую группу выделяются **трехчленные конструкции**, например: Ее уста, как розы, рдеют.

Здесь сравниваются **два предмета** через  их отношению **к действию**. Каким членом является оборот, обособленным приложением или обстоятельством?  Оба ответа кажутся неправомерными для таких трехчастных конструкций. (Материал взят из книги Прияткина А.Ф. Синтаксис осложненного предложения, 2019 год, 2-е издание, стереотипное. Учебник для вузов.)

Можно ли самостоятельно  рассуждать  на столь сложную тему, не будучи знакомым с общепринятыми на сегодняшний день разработками. Мне это представляется делом рискованным – утонуть в таких темных и малоизученных глубинах  как нечего делать.

**Еще пара слово о терминологии.**  **Детерминация** – это в общем случае определение чего-либо, так что обстоятельство как второстепенный член можно назвать **обстоятельственным детерминантом**. Но вроде бы сейчас такой термин  не в ходу, а детерминантом называют **второстепенный член**, который не имеет грамматических связей с конкретным словом, а относится ко всему составу предложения, то есть к его предикативной основе. Чаще всего это обстоятельство в начале предложения, например: *По вечерам вся семья собиралась дома*.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2 (о сущностном свойстве предмета сравнения)**

В приведенных предложениях нужно отличать сравнительный союз КАК  от сочинительного союза КАК И.

**Союз КАК И**  синонимичен союзу КАК…ТАК И  и  является **сочинительным** союзом:   этот, как и тот;  как тот, так другой. Предлагаемые предложения можно построить с помощью союза КАК И, но тогда соединяемые части будут обозначены **как независимые**: Этот мир, как и дитя, нам послушен. Рубли, как и доллары, нам нужны.

**А вот сравнительный союз КАК** сочинительную связь не образует, здесь требуются **особые отношения**. Один предмет сравнивается с другим, но при этом второй предмет является **носителем определенного абстрактного качества.**  Так строится вся фразеология с союзом КАК, а также авторские сравнения, но в любом случае читатель должен понимать,  **о каком качестве** идет речь (красный как рак, легкий как пух, блестит как зеркало) .

Мы можем сказать: **мир, как дитя, нам послушен** (сравнение); *мир как дитЯ нам послушен (степень признака)*,  так как ребенок  обозначает **идею послушания**. Но мы  не можем сказать: рубли, как доллары, нужны. Эти предметы мыслятся как независимые (правильно: *рубли, как и доллары, нам нужны*).  Но можно сказать: *мне сейчас деньги как воздух нужны.*  Воздух имеет абстрактное значение **абсолютной нужности** для человека.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 3 (почему не нужно изобретать велосипед)**

В принципе об этом говорится часто, даже у моих любимых авторов:

… Я давно к вам присматриваюсь! Вы славный молодой человек! При всем том у вас есть **серьезный изъян!** Изъян! Вы недоверчивы. Зачем доказывать, что, если ткнуть иголкой в руку, пойдет кровь? Поверьте хоть раз кому-то на слово! **Нельзя пойти далеко в науке, каждый день изобретая велосипеды…**

И где-то еще я читала **интересную метафору** на эту тему. Там говорилось, что в любой науке нужно постараться доехать до конечной станции имеющихся знаний и только потом прокладывать собственную дорогу.

**Другой вопрос – как это сделать,** ведь можно так и не сдвинуться  места, попав под авторитет предыдущих авторов. Раскованное, свободное мышление тоже нужно, а вот как его достичь. Свое мировоззрение нужно строить не по чужим образцам – полученные из книг знания должны быть осмыслены вами **как ваши собственные.**

Нужно научиться свободно оперировать ими, но в любой момент будьте готовы **дать ссылку на мнение авторитетов**, если вы использовали их знания.

**А если не использовали?**  Тогда это значит, что вы изобретаете велосипед,  а в науке пытаетесь проложить собственную тропинку от самых истоков, в то время как рядом проходит обкатанное многими поколениями шоссе.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133899/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------).

Comment: Про конечную станцию знаний. Как до неё дойти? Изучить всё, что существует? Ещё ж куча денег нужно, чтоб столько книг купить. Но главное: как получить список всего того, что существует? Нет, учёные изучают то, что им интересно, столько, сколько считают достаточным. Никто не в силах найти всё и получить к нему доступ. Потому что никак не узнать, это всё или же нет.

Comment: @Sharon Емец, значит, из любимых писателей? Это плохо: мне как раз ваш эйдос приглянулся, а раз вы знаете, что к чему, трудновато будет его добыть...

Comment: @oleedd
 – Мой конь притомился, стоптались мои башмаки.
Куда же мне ехать? Скажите мне, будьте добры.
– Вдоль Красной реки, моя радость, вдоль Красной реки,
до Синей горы, моя радость, до Синей горы.

– А где ж та река, та гора? Притомился мой конь.
Скажите, пожалуйста, как мне проехать туда?
– На ясный огонь, моя радость, на ясный огонь,
езжай на огонь, моя радость, найдешь без труда.
https://teksty-pesenok.ru/rus-bulat-okudzhava/tekst-pesni-nochnoj-razgovor/1756305/
Все мы тут души неприкаянные и заблудшие…

Comment: @Nektoid
   Ах вы, «черная мышка», охотник за эйдосами!  Что-то наш форум стал популярен  для  разных сущностей, кто только не заглядывает. Тут недавно забежал один такой на огонек – кстати, и вы там в это время были… Как он там сказал?  Надо…побольше молчать. Пусть говорят Мудрецы!  Хороший совет, не находите? Так и эйдос целее будет…